# Does web3.js have deserialization methods?

Tags: web3js

Looking at the code of **web.js**'s **utils.toHex()**:

```
/**
 * Auto converts any given value into it's hex representation.
 *
 * And even stringifys objects before.
 *
 * @method toHex
 * @param {String|Number|BigNumber|Object}
 * @return {String}
 */
var toHex = function (val) {
    /*jshint maxcomplexity: 8 */

    if (isBoolean(val))
        return fromDecimal(+val);

    if (isBigNumber(val))
        return fromDecimal(val);

    if (isObject(val))
        return fromUtf8(JSON.stringify(val));

    // if its a negative number, pass it through fromDecimal
    if (isString(val)) {
        if (val.indexOf('-0x') === 0)
            return fromDecimal(val);
        else if(val.indexOf('0x') === 0)
            return val;
        else if (!isFinite(val))
            return fromAscii(val);
    }

    return fromDecimal(val);
};

/**
 * Should be called to get hex representation (prefixed by 0x) of utf8 string
 *
 * @method fromUtf8
 * @param {String} string
 * @param {Number} optional padding
 * @returns {String} hex representation of input string
 */
var fromUtf8 = function(str) {
    str = utf8.encode(str);
    var hex = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code === 0)
            break;
        var n = code.toString(16);
        hex += n.length < 2 ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    return "0x" + hex;
};
```

it returns a JSON serialized object when given an object but I can't seem to find an inverse function of **fromUtf8(toHex())**, the "unhex" function.

Does **web3.js** have one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the same file, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/utils/utils.js#L97) (line 97):

```
/**
 * Should be called to get utf8 from it's hex representation
 *
 * @method toUtf8
 * @param {String} string in hex
 * @returns {String} ascii string representation of hex value
 */
var toUtf8 = function(hex) {
```

The associated test file is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/test/utils.toUtf8.js).